# What is the mistake in the following?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that ${1\over i} = -i$ where $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Can anyone figure out the mistake in the following lines?

**1/i = 1/squareroot(-1) = squareroot(1)/squareroot(-1) = squareroot(1/(-1)) = squareroot(-1/1) = squareroot(-1) = i**

${1\over i}={1\over \sqrt{-1}}={\sqrt{1}\over \sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt{1\over -1}=\sqrt{-1\over 1}=\sqrt{-1}=i$

Which is a contradiction? I tried hard, but I am not able to figure out what's wrong with the above equations. Thank You.

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{-1}$? There are actually two square roots of $-1$: $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times {-1}} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12)

Comment: Here's a similar calculation only involving real numbers: $1=\sqrt{1^2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=-1$. Find the error in that calculation, and you'll probably find the error in yours.

Comment: Problem is due to $\sqrt$ being multivalued function.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096917/can-someone-prove-why-sqrtab-sqrta-sqrtb-is-only-valid-when-a-and-b-ar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply found one of the instances where, after defining $\sqrt\bullet:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ to be [the principal value of the square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number), you must face the fact that some identities you were familiar with for the usual square root $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ no longer hold: it is not, in this generality, the case that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}$, or that $\sqrt{\frac ab}=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt b}$, or even that $\sqrt{\frac1b}=\frac{1}{\sqrt b}$.

Comment: "You simply found one of the instances where, after defining $\sqrt{\bullet}:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ to be "the only continuous function $f$ that satisfies $f^2=id$ and such that $f(−1)=i$"" — If you define $\sqrt{\bullet}$ like this, you will find it undefined. There is no continuous function with these properties.

Comment: @celtischk True. That was a *very* poor (very wrong) wording of what a had in  mind.

Comment: Are there any general rules for the indices of complex numbers? If yes can you share some source. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac 1i = \frac 1i \cdot \frac{-i}{-i} = \frac {-i}{-i^2} = \frac {-i}{-(-1)} = \frac {-i}{1} = -i$$

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b \geq 0$ (and $b \neq 0$) then we have that $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$. Now tell me: are both $1, -1\geq 0$?

Comment: You need the converse of your first sentence to show that the steps given by the OP are wrong. An "iff" would help too.

Comment: you are absolutely right, answered to quick, my bad!