# Why is $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b} $ where a and b are positive real numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

That's the question.

I try to explain this to myself I can't find any good resources.

Note: I have researched for about 15 mins and yet haven't found the answer.
I do apologize for any inconveniences.

Comment: Due to the same reason $x^2 y^2 =(xy)(xy)$.

Comment: Actually it isn't, if you allow $a$ and $b$ to be negative.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096917/can-someone-prove-why-sqrtab-sqrta-sqrtb-is-only-valid-when-a-and-b-ar to notice why $a,b$ must be positive.

Comment: This is not linear algebra.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481316/sqrtab-sqrta-sqrtb-for-complex-number-a-and-b to find all complex numbers $a,b$ that satisfy $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square root of a number $a$ is defined as "number, which when multiplied by itself, gives $a$", also $\left(\sqrt{a}\right)^2 = a$.

We can clearly see that if $\sqrt{a}\times\sqrt{a} = a$ and $\sqrt{b}\times\sqrt{b} = b$, then by multiplying both sides we get $\sqrt{a}\times\sqrt{a}\times\sqrt{b}\times\sqrt{b} = ab$.

But we already know, that $\sqrt{ab}\times\sqrt{ab}=ab$, from the definition.

And now it is obvious - $\sqrt{a}\times\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$.
Similarly for other roots.

Comment: Just a small remark: The squareroot ist defined as "positive number [...]"

Comment: @PaulK You're correct in that a nonzero number generally has two square roots, but we define the notation $\sqrt{x}$ to refer to the positive square root of $x$ when $x$ is a positive real number. It would be incorrect to say that $\sqrt{9} = \pm 3$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $\sqrt{n}$ is "the number which gives $n$ when you square it.
So notice that $(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b})^2 = \sqrt{a}^2\sqrt{b}^2 = ab.$  Since you get $ab$ when you square $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$, it must be that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is the square root of $ab$, which is to say $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}.$

Who's buried in Grant's tomb?

Comment: Just a small remark: The squareroot ist defined as "the positive number which gives [...]"