# Why we say $i^2 = -1$ while it is $1$

Tags: complex-numbers

If we have 
$$\sqrt[2]{x}^{2} = \sqrt[2]{x^2} = |x|$$
so : 
$$\sqrt[2]{-1}^{2} = \sqrt[2]{-1^2} = |-1| = 1$$
so why we say $i^2 = -1$?

Comment: Well I say that $i^2$ equals $-1$ because it equals $-1$. I don't say $i^2$ equal $1$ because it doesn't equal $1$.

Comment: This question is massively a duplicate, but I can't find the One True Answer - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096917/can-someone-prove-why-sqrtab-sqrta-sqrtb-is-only-valid-when-a-and-b-ar?rq=1 is an example.

Comment: Logical reason? It's the definition of $i$...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x^2}\neq (\sqrt{x})^2$$