# 6=-6? Is it possible?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

Recently my friend showed me this proof. I know this is wrong but I don't know accurate reasons. Can anyone help?

His proof:

$6 = \sqrt{\frac{-9}{-4}} 
    = \sqrt{-9} \times \sqrt{-4}
    = 3i × 2i
    = 6×(i^2) = -6$

Comment: I guess something is wrong in the 2nd step... but what?

Comment: $\sqrt{ab} =\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ holds only for non negative real numbers $a,b$

Comment: Every non-zero complex number has **two** square roots. All this boils down to is saying "$6^2=(-6)^2$ so $6=-6$".

Comment: @Pratik.garai As said in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096917/) Math SE post, there are two answers for $\sqrt{-9}$ ($+3i$ and $-3i$), and two answers for $\sqrt{-4}$ ($+2i$ and $-2i$). When you multiply them, you get the four possibilities of $-6$, $6$, $6$ and $-6$. However, only the first and last possibilities make sense, and your friend is just selecting the one that doesn't make sense.

Comment: When we square root a number, it is just convention that the **principal** square root is the positive one. The negative one still exists.